# Vertica UNION and ORDER BY

Tags: order-by, union, vertica

I want to use ORDER BY clause but still have one specific entry on the top.
I thought this might do it but Vertica is ignoring the ORDER BY clause on the second query:

```
(SELECT country_id, country_name 
FROM country_dim 
WHERE country_dim.iso_country_code LIKE 'US')
UNION 
(SELECT country_id, country_name 
FROM country_dim 
WHERE country_dim.iso_country_code NOT LIKE 'US' 
ORDER BY country_name ASC)
```

Resulting in

```
12  United States of America
10  Germany
5   Brazil
6   Canada
7   China
8   France
4   Algeria
3   Aland Islands
2   Albania
8   Denmark
11  United Arab Emirates
13  Central African Republic
-1  Unknown
14  Svalbard and Jan Mayen
```

DDL is

```
CREATE TABLE country_dim
(
    country_id int NOT NULL,
    iso_country_code char(2) NOT NULL,
    country_name varchar(512) NOT NULL,
    create_ts timestamptz,
    update_ts timestamptz
);

ALTER TABLE country_dim ADD CONSTRAINT country_dim_pk PRIMARY KEY (country_id) DISABLED;
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The query needs `ORDER BY` in the end, not in the subqueries (and note that the parentheses are optional there, at least in standard SQL, not sure if Vertica requires them):

```
( SELECT country_id, country_name 
  FROM country_dim 
  WHERE iso_country_code LIKE 'US')
UNION 
( SELECT country_id, country_name 
  FROM country_dim 
  WHERE iso_country_code NOT LIKE 'US')     -- without ORDER BY
ORDER BY 
    CASE WHEN iso_country_code LIKE 'US' THEN 0 ELSE 1 END ASC,
    country_name ASC ;
```

But since you are grabbing all the data from the same table, there is no need for the `UNION` and the subqueries:

```
SELECT country_id, country_name 
FROM country_dim 
ORDER BY 
    CASE WHEN iso_country_code LIKE 'US' THEN 0 ELSE 1 END ASC,
    country_name ASC ;
```